# programmatically determine if a certain gem is installed, then install it if not

Tags: ruby, rubygems

This doesn't seem like it would be a hard thing to do.

I want a ruby script that figures out if a certain gem (any version, and/or a certain version spec) is currently installed on the system (wherever `gem list` will look), and if not, installs it.

Yes, I know in some cases bundler is great at that. Trust me that I have a case where for weird reasons I don't want to use bundler. I really do want to programmatically interrogate the local gem repo.

One way to programmatially install is just to shell out to `gem install`, sure.

But I can't manage to figure out a reliable way to programmatically *interrogate* to see if a particular gem is installed, not with shell out, not with rubygem api, not anything.

Am I missing it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
# The version requirements are optional.
# You can also specify multiple version requirements, just append more at the end
gem_name, *gem_ver_reqs = 'json', '~> 1.8.0'
gdep = Gem::Dependency.new(gem_name, *gem_ver_reqs)
# find latest that satisifies
found_gspec = gdep.matching_specs.max_by(&:version)
# instead of using Gem::Dependency, you can also do:
# Gem::Specification.find_all_by_name(gem_name, *gem_ver_reqs)

if found_gspec
  puts "Requirement '#{gdep}' already satisfied by #{found_gspec.name}-#{found_gspec.version}"
else
  puts "Requirement '#{gdep}' not satisfied; installing..."
  # reqs_string will be in the format: "> 1.0, < 1.2"
  reqs_string = gdep.requirements_list.join(', ')
  # multi-arg is safer, to avoid injection attacks
  system('gem', 'install', gem_name, '-v', reqs_string)
end
```

More recent rubygems versions provide an installer API, so instead of shelling out to the `gem` command you could also use:

```
# using the same "gdep" variable as above
Gem.install gem_name, gdep.requirement
```

However, I'm not sure if `Gem.install` respects your `.gemrc` file.

There are a lot of useful methods for querying your installed gems (see [rdocs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/index.html)). Some that might be helpful:

- `Gem::Specification.find_all_by_name`
- `Gem::Requirement#satisfied_by?(gem_version_instance)`
- `Gem::Specification#satisfies_requirement?(gem_dependency_instance)`
- `Gem.loaded_specs` - hash of the gems you've actually loaded via the `gem` method, or by `require`

Comment: perfect answer exactly what i was looking for, thank for providing examples of several api methods instead of just one. The rubygems ruby code api is difficult to get an overview understanding of, thanks for the examples!

Answer (score 20):

Last answer was good, but this is a little more precise:

```
`gem install redis` unless `gem list`.lines.grep(/^redis \(.*\)/)
```

Matches only the gem named `redis`, and not other gems like `redis-native_hash`, or something else.

Another way I've seen this done is to try requiring the gem.

```
begin
  require 'some_crazy_gem'
rescue LoadError
  `gem install some_crazy_gem`
  #...
end
```

Comment: Yeah, I was gonna say "No, not any gem beginning 'redis'", but I guess your regexp with the space in it catches that?  Still kind of amazed there's no less hacky way to do this. For instance, there's no command like `gem list` but which only returns exact matches rather than substrings?

Comment: You could also try `gem which gem-name`. If the response starts with ERROR its not there.

Comment: nice, that's good too. Now if only there were a way to check for a specific version of a specific gem!  It's kind of crazy that rubygems doesn't have reliable ruby api for all this stuff, and everyone resorts to screen scraping a shell out.

Comment: @jrochkind see my answer - it doesn't rely on the `gem` command. A tip when you're on the command-line is to use `gem query -n '^json$'`, but this isn't good for detecting a specific version, because you'd have to parse the version numbers in the output.

Comment: I prefer the `rescue LoadError` approach because `gem install` requires admin privileges on many systems.  In the rescue block, print a message to STDERR spelling out the `gem install` command and exit.

Comment: Wish I could escape the backtick in comment. In the following use backtick instead of single quote in every occurance: For me, running `'gem list'.lines.grep(/^redis \(.*\)/)` in irb without redis installed returns an empty array. Shouldn't we use `.blank?` or `.empty?` to check if the results are blank because empty array is `true` just like a non-empty array. I am new to Ruby but this works for me: `'gem install redis' if 'gem list'.lines.grep(/^redis \(.*\)/).empty?` The code above doesn't work. Maybe it has something to do with my version of ruby. I am on `1.9.3`.

Answer (score 4):

Check that there is installed a gem newer than a particular version.

```
PROMPT> gem list nakamoto -i -v ">=1.2.3"
true
```

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea if this is a best practice or not but:

```
list = `gem list`
`gem install builder` unless list.include? "builder"
```

... worked for me in irb.

Comment: I was looking for a solution that did not involve a shell out to command line, but could be done in ruby code. the accepted answer is such